# Clicar sobre uma informação, aparecer um campo texto, alterar a informação e salvar automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Como posso fazer para que o usuário clique sobre uma informação vinda do BD, essa informação se transforme em um campo texto, a pessoa altera a informação e quando clicar fora do campo, salvar automaticamente? Como ocorre no PHPMyadmin.

Comment: Você gera o `input` dinamicamente no DOM, com o valor atual do banco; quando o campo receber o evento `blur` você faz uma requisição atualizando no banco. Quer tentar?

Comment: Olá Anderson. Você poderia me dar um exemplo? Pois confesso que não tenho muita experiência com Jquery.

Comment: Um **contenteditable** não resolveria seu caso?

Comment: Certo LeAndrade, mas como eu faria para que, através do Jquery, pudesse alterar o conteúdo do BD (Mysql)? O PHP que faz a edição está tudo ok, apenas gostaria de que ao clicar sobre o texto, aparecesse o campo, conforme você passou, mas ao clicar fora do campo, atualizasse automaticamente no BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue abaixo um exemplo básico de como você pode apresentar essa interação. No exemplo abaixo eu estou habilitando a edição para os elementos `<p>` e `<h2>` e você pode utilizar os seletores que achar adequados assim como realizar a persistência ao banco de dados realizando um post ajax para o seu php.

```js
let editar = function(elemento) {
  let original = elemento;
  original.hide();

  let editor = $('<input type="text" />').insertAfter(original);
  editor.val(original.text());
  editor.on('blur', () => {
    let novoConteudo = $(editor).val();
    original.text(novoConteudo);

    // Aqui você poderia persitir o conteúdo no banco
    // via ajax

    $(editor).detach();
    original.show();
  });
  editor.focus();
};

$(document).ready(() => {
 
 //Seletor dos elementos que você deseja que sejam editaveis
 let containers = $('body').children('p, h2')
 
 $.each(containers, (index) => {
    let elemento = containers[index];
    //adiciona o evento de click
    $(elemento).on('click', () => {
      editar($(elemento))
    });

    //altera a aprencia do cursor
    $(elemento).hover(
      function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>Titulo original</h2>
  <p id='teste'>Texto original</p>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Perfeito Leandro. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fox.11 está longe da perfeição, mas acho que é um ponto de partida para você trabalhar em cima.